Error when running mpi4py program on Linux.mpi
I am running Linux (Pop!_OS), and I am trying to run my program using mpi. However,
It doesn't work for python scripts (with mpi4py)
but it kinda works for C scripts. (with mpi.h)
To test it out I've ran a simple program where the program should output hello {rank} out of {size}. Where rank is the current processor that will print the line and size is the total number of processors that are used.
My program: hello.py
### hello.py ###
from mpi4py import MPI
MPI = MPI.COMM_WORLD
size = comm.size
rank = comm.rank

print(f"{rank} of {size}")

This is the output that I get for mpirun -np 4 python3 hello.py
hwloc/linux: Ignoring PCI device with non-16bit domain.
Pass --enable-32bits-pci-domain to configure to support such devices
(warning: it would break the library ABI, don't enable unless really needed).

above messages is repeated 8 times with the following at the end
hello 0 of 1
hello 0 of 1
hello 0 of 1
hello 0 of 1

I have a similar program that I made in C, hello.c
/*hello.c*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int size, rank;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    printf("Hello %d out of %d\n", rank, size);

    MPI_Finalize();
}

compiled using mpicc and then running: mpirun -np 4 ./hello. I get the same error message but only once with the output at the end:
hwloc/linux: Ignoring PCI device with non-16bit domain.
Pass --enable-32bits-pci-domain to configure to support such devices
(warning: it would break the library ABI, don't enable unless really needed).
Hello 0 out of 4
Hello 2 out of 4
Hello 3 out of 4
Hello 1 out of 4

Though this gives the desired output, I don't know what do do with get the hwloc/linux... prompt. I want to fix it so it can run correctly for mpi4py as well.
Additional Detail:

I have a dual-boot system, the other OS is Windows on a separate SSD. The same programs work fine on Windows.


look at the comments in the very same question you posted 10 days ago.

@GillesGouaillardet Oh you  answered the last question as well. I tried reinstalling it again. It didn't work. I am getting the exact errors.

I couldn't understand the output provided with strace python3 hello.py either. I tried to use grep libmpi.so to the output for strace, but the resutls say openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v4/libmpi.so.40", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) for every libmpi.so at different directories. However I am unsure what do with this information.

what does python -c "from mpi4py import MPI; print(MPI.Get_library_version())" say?

@GillesGouaillardet I'm getting the same hwloc... error right after importing the library. However, the print statement shows the library version: Open MPI v4.1.2, package: Debian OpenMPI, ident: 4.1.2, repo rev: v4.1.2, Nov 24, 2021. This shows both prompts within ipython

go back to the first question an read again the first comment.

@GillesGouaillardet I read your comment the first time as well. What I still don't understand is how to fix the problem. I have  openmpi-bin, openmpi-common, and mpich when I searching using dpkg -l. I have tried reinstalling mpi4py following your suggestions as well. It doesn't seem to work for me. A bit more guidance would be appreciated. These are my installed packages related to openmpi and mpich.

Since mpi4py was built for Open MPI, you must use mpiexec from the same Open MPI version.

@GillesGouaillardet Hi! It's finally fixed, I had two different installation of MPICH, and one of them I manually installed sometime ago from the MPICH website. I removed that, then installed mpi using the apt package manager, and also reinstalled mpi4py. The problem is now fixed, i.e. the output for hello.py is the same as it was for hello.c in the post. However I am still getting the hwloc message. But I am not sure if I should just ignore it, since my program is running fine.
